# How to begin approach of creating a small lazily-evaluated language

Tags: compiler-construction, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to build a small language with similar syntax and grammatical structure to Java, with List Comprehension and Lambda Functions and such (already made).

What I'm trying to do now is instead of having it do eager evaluation, I want to make this language lazily-evaluate expressions. I'm not entirely sure how to go about it, because I don't have a clear idea of how to do partial evaluation.

I've done a lot of googling and come up with no answer, so I was wondering if anyone here had a good reference on this.

Any takers?

Comment: Do you want to add the lazily evaluated lambda expressions to an imperative language, or just write a lazy language?

Comment: I want to add lazy evaluation to all forms of function passing and list comprehension. H-- allows for higher-order functions and thus lambda expressions and list comprehension with generators.

Comment: Only it is evaluated eagerly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Haskell_Performance) from the Haskell Wikibook might be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks! I think this will help me find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The paper over designing/developing  functional programming languages bij Simon Peyton Jones [here](http://research.microsoft.com/~simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/) 
might be useful.